Generate lost keystore file with pepk and pem file
I work for a company that built an android app for another company. I joined a few months ago and the previous dev did not save the keystore file, nor do i have the necessary access to reset the key.
What we have is the following:

file without an ending(no .jks, or similar, just the file name which is the app name)
private_key.pepk file
upload_certificate.pem file

I am not well versed with keys/certificates etc. but from my research so far, there doesn't seem to be a way to generate the actually jks i need for uploading an app update.
Of course, my boss does not want to tell the other company about the problem, as they will probably think that we are incompetent(which probably is true, if we can't even store a key)..
I tried to find information on this problem on googles websites, but there doesn't seem to be any documentation regarding this problem. The easy solution is probably to tell the other company that they need to reset the keystore and provide us with it, together with alias and key/password..

Step 1:
Login into the dedicated play console from where the app got uploaded.
Step 2:
Click on App signing from left menu side.

Step 3:
Click on "Request upload key reset", now you'll see like below. From there select "I forgot the password to my keystore"

Step 4:
Now go to Android studio -> Build -> Generate Signed App bundle/apk -> Apk -> Next -> Create New -> Now give all the inputs
Finally create a new FILENAME.jks file and then also save the given KeyAlias and KeyPassword. (You may save these info to your drive)



Step 5:
Now we'll generate .pem file from our newly created .jks file. So, firstly we will find the newly created .jks file path into our Windows/Mac. Just copy the path.
Then open your android studio terminal and paste this command, and then hit Enter (It will ask you to give input of last newly created KeyPassword):
keytool -export -rfc -keystore YOUR_NEWLY_CREATED_KEYSTORE_PATH -alias YOUR_NEWLY_CREATED_KEY_ALIAS_NAME -file upload_certificate.pem

If all okay you'll see this message into terminal.
Certificate stored in file <upload_certificate.pem>

Step 6:
Now go to step 3 and then from number 4. upload your generated .pem file and click on "Request" button.
Step 7:
When google mails you with confirmation, you can upload bundle to playconsole again with the new .jks.
Happy coding :)
